# How to Make Object.class Type Generic

Tags: java, jaxb

I would like to create a utility method that takes two Objects as parameters and marshalls a XML from them.  The below code works if I use the actual Object type for the from parameter, but how do I make this generic? The below wont compile since it can't resolve the from Object to a type. Any ideas?

```
 public static String getXML(Object from){
    StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
    try {
      JAXBContext.newInstance(from.class).createMarshaller().marshal(from, xml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `Class` class? You can do `from.getClass()`. This will only work if `to` is of the same type.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry typo in my code, fixed now...please add your comment as an answer so i can accept

Comment: What you've posted is definitely wrong now. You need `from.getClass()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Class` instance of an object like so

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(from.getClass()) //...
```

This is explained in the [`Ojbect#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) javadoc.

> Returns the runtime class of this Object.

Note that there aren't any generics directly involved in this code snippet.